# unable to find asp checkbox by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I am unable to find the asp:checkbox on my asp web app using the FindControl method. I put a checkbox on my form using:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="test" Text="Test checkbox" runat="server" />
```

In my codebehind I have the following:

```
Control checkbox = FindControl("test");
if (checkbox != null) Debug.Print("checkbox found");
else Debug.Print("checkbox not found");

if (test.Checked) Debug.Print("checkbox is checked");
else Debug.Print("checkbox is unchecked");
```

however my output (with the checkbox checked) is:
checkbox not found
checkbox is checked

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you just reference your checkbox without using FindControl?

Comment: If you can use firebug and try to find the id of that checkbox

Comment: @heatStroke please can you put the actual code from your code-behind

Comment: is the checkbox in the pannel

Comment: The reason I need FindControl is because there are actually a lot of checkboxes on my form which I would like to be able to find programatically. The checkboxes are not in a panel, table or other container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FindControl` method **is not recursive** and will only find your control if you call it on the **immediate parent** of the checkbox. So for example, if the checkbox is placed inside an `UpdatePanel` that's also inside the Page; you need to call `FindControl` on the `UpdatePanel` and not `Page.FindControl` as you are doing.

The reason your output says: `checkbox not found checkbox is checked` is because you are calling `test.checked` directly, which will always work since that's the ID you gave to your checkbox.

Again, `FindControl` is not recursive and I am positive that's why it's failing. You can write your own "RecursiveFindControl" method but that's almost always an overkill and inefficient as hell.

Comment: Thanks, I put all of my controls in a asp:table and my problems are solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive method to find the control in following way:

```
private Control RecursiveFindControl(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id) return root;
    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        Control t = RecursiveFindControl(c, id);
        if (t != null) return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use above  recursive method to find the control:

```
CheckBox checkbox =  RecursiveFindControl(Page, "test") as CheckBox;
if (checkbox != null) Debug.Print("checkbox found");
else Debug.Print("checkbox not found");

if (test.Checked) Debug.Print("checkbox is checked");
else Debug.Print("checkbox is unchecked");
```

Comment: Precisely what I think is a bad approach and you suggested it! LOL The moment one starts using this method in a control really deep in the control tree you end up with a page slow as a turtle. I had to profile a page using this technique once, and the amount of calls to the recursive function sometimes surpassed the thousands. More than 70% of the time was spent only trying to find a control that could be found in one or 2 function calls at the most.

Comment: @Icarus : I am not suggesting OP to use abvoe recursive method but just giving him a alternative to find the control through recursion....

Comment: @LolCoder: thanks for the help, I am sure this will come in handy in the future!